# Uncaught TypeError: el.target is not a function in Cytoscape

Tags: cytoscape.js

It is an example whose title is "images-breadthfirst-layout" in cytoscape js 
(https://github.com/cytoscape/cytoscape.js/blob/unstable/documentation/demos/images-breadthfirst-layout/code.js)

```
cy.on('tap', 'node', function(){
var nodes = this;
var tapped = nodes;
var food = [];

nodes.addClass('eater');

for(;;){
  var connectedEdges = nodes.connectedEdges(function(el){   <-- here
    return !el.target().anySame( nodes );
});
```

When i run this example, I have this error in chrome:

```
code.js:106 Uncaught TypeError: el.target is not a function
    at a.<anonymous> (code.js:106)
    at s.filter (cytoscape.min.js:18)
    at a.connectedEdges (cytoscape.min.js:18)
    at a.<anonymous> (code.js:105)
    at u.<anonymous> (cytoscape.min.js:19)
    at a.<anonymous> (cytoscape.min.js:19)
    at t (cytoscape.min.js:21)
    at cytoscape.min.js:21
```

how can i solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to [download Cytoscape only from the master branch](https://github.com/cytoscape/cytoscape.js/tree/master/dist) or from npm.  Similarly, make sure to use the [demo code only from the master branch](https://github.com/cytoscape/cytoscape.js/tree/master/documentation/demos/images-breadthfirst-layout).

The docs link only to the master branch.